# Why is this question (install Sony Xperia kernel dev) marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/412396/181442) with a link to [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/318247/181442) which I used to install the Android SDK.

My question, however, asks about the kernel sources for Sony Xperia ZR, as it can be downloaded from the Sony webpage.

Although I added the `sony` tag and put `Sony Xperia ZR` into the title from the very beginning, I soon got a vote for "duplicate", along with the removal of the `sony` tag (which I just added again for clarity).

Indeed, if you were to remove Sony from the title and tags, this question *would* be a duplicate of the question to the answer linked above.

Can someone explain/review this please?

Comment: That looks like a good standalone question to me, I've voted to reopen.

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCastro. I also noticed that you took away my edit to make it obvious that it is about Xperia devices, I guess you thought that the original question was clear enough?

Comment: The title is very clear and specific, that's half the battle!